# rebuild in batch with buildbot

Tags: continuous-integration, buildbot

I'm using buildbot for few months now and I'm really happy with it. It's plugged with github.

I'm working on a image processing software, and processing time is really important. Until recently, I was doing automatic build + tests, and I'm now monitoring time spend with the tests.

Because monitoring of processing time has been implemented just recently, I'd like to build all the previous commit since few months, so I can see some potential processing time drawback.

I can trigger manual build on a particular commit with the [ForceScheduler](http://buildbot.net/buildbot/docs/latest/developer/cls-forcesched.html), but is there an easy way to do that on the last 500 commits for instance ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have PBSource configured as a changesource, you can simply write a script to call `buildbot sendchange` on the command line.

```
buildbot sendchange --master {MASTERHOST}:{PORT} --auth {USER}:{PASS}
    --who {USER} {FILENAMES..}
```

see: http://buildbot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/cmdline.html